# Flutter nested provider not getting the latest values despite notifyListeners() being called

Tags: flutter

Say, I have 2 widgets, A and B, where B is nested inside A. Both widgets are wrapped using Consumer. However, only widget A is able to get latest values from the provider, whereas widget B remains as the initial state.

```
class WidgetA extends StatelessWidget {
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final FooProvider fooProvider = Provider.of<FooProvider>(context, listen: false);
   fooProvider.fetchData();
        return Consumer<FooProvider>(
            builder: (context, value, child) { 
                print(value.modelList[0].name); //able to get latest value whenever changes are made to FooProvider.
                return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async {
            foodProvider.fetchData();
                        return showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return WidgetB(); //NOTICE I'm calling WidgetB here
                            }
                        )
                    },
                    child: WidgetB(); //NOTICE I'm calling WidgetB here
                );
            }
        )
    }
}

class WidgetB extends StatelessWidget {
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Consumer<FooProvider>(
            builder: (context, value, child) { 
                print(value.modelList[0].name); //unable to get latest in showDialog
                return Container();
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**EDIT** The code for ChangeNotifier:
It's just a regular Provider doing its work.

```
List<FooModel> modelList = [];
bool isWithinTimeFrame = false;

Future<void> fetchData(email, token, url) async {
    await Service(
      email,
      token,
    ).fetchCutOff(url).then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
        bool isSuccess = jsonResponse["success"];

        if (isSuccess) {
          dynamic formattedResponse = jsonResponse["data"];
          List<FooModel> modelList = formattedResponse
              .map<FooModel>((json) => FooModel.fromJson(json))
              .toList();

          setModelList(modelList);
          setIsWithinTimeFrame(computeTime(modelList));
        } else {}
      } else {}
    });
}


void setModelList(value) {
    modelList = value;
    notifyListeners();
}

void setIsWithinTimeFrame(value) {
    isWithinTimeFrame = value;
    notifyListeners();
}
```

Comment: I advise you to use StatefulWidget.

Comment: Add more relevant code.

Comment: @Akif does it matter if I'm already using provider?

Comment: @TirthPatel l added more code to WidgetA, notice this only happens when I call WidgetB inside a `showDialog`

Comment: Can you add model (ChangeNotifier) code?

Comment: @TirthPatel Just added in the Model code.

Comment: Where you call fetchData?

Comment: just edited more code, calling in both widget build and onTap